# The area enclosed $f(x)=3\sqrt x$, $x=1 $and $y=0$ is bisected into two regions of equal

Tags: calculus

the area enclosed $f(x)=3\sqrt x$, $x=1 \text { and } y=0$ is bisected into two regions of equal are by the line described as $y=mx.$ Find m?

Please help me?

My attemp: ARea of the:
$$\int_0^1 3\sqrt x dx =2$$

we have to find some constant $m∈(0,3)$ such that the area between $y=3\sqrt x$ and $y=mx$ is 1.

Now,
$$\int_{-3}^3 (\frac{y^2}{9}-\frac{y}{m}) dx =1$$  and find $m$, or not

Comment: Try writing the area in terms of $m$ using integrals.

Comment: Try writing the entire area as an integral first.

Comment: i didnt know how to do that, show me, 
that he could then proceed on his own

Comment: [This link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html) on definite integrals will help you.  Edit your post to show your work, then we could help you.

Comment: sir i now the indifinite integral, but i didnt know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enclosed area can be evaluated to be $$A=\int_0^13\sqrt x\,dx=2.$$

The region enclosed by $y=mx$ and the $x$-axis between $x=0$ and $x=1$ forms a triangle, which has a basic formula of $\dfrac12\left(\text{base}\times\text{height}\right)$.  Since the base of the triangle is exactly $1$ and we need this area to be exactly $1$, this is achieved by selecting $m=2$, since $m$ is exactly the height of the triangle.

Comment: finally m, is 2, sir